# How do you move an Xcode 4.2 project file to another folder?

Tags: xcode, projects-and-solutions

Not crazy about the way Xcode 4.2 has laid out the files on disk.  It creates a project file, then a single subfolder next to it that has all the code.  We want the project file to be in that same folder, then the workspace file (if any) to be the folder's sibling.  Makes for more portable layouts.

However, I can't STAND the lack of Save-as in Lion, and now, apparently Xcode 4.2 as well.  At least with TextEdit I just grabbed the version from SL and it works.  No such luck with Xcode as as you know, it's a completely different animal than Xcode 3.x.

So... how does one move/rename the project file relative to the source code?

Comment: I assume you don't want to do this manually in the Finder?  Because you can if you really need to move the files.

Comment: Actually, you can't.  If you move the project, all the file references are broken, but even if you manually fix them all, the build settings are still all borked.  Even attempting to fix them manually in the build-settings grid doesn't fix everything.  The old paths are still passed to the compiler.

Comment: The fix (i.e. hack/workaround) that I came up with was to simply delete all references to the files in the project, close it, rearrange them in finder, reopen the project, then manually add back all the files, correcting the build settings as needed.  Wasn't too bad since I only have about 40 files, but it's f***ing ridiculous that there's no 'Save as' command.  Apple really screwed the pooch with that change in Lion.  One of their biggest mistakes ever.  Lion to me is Apple's 'Vista' moment.

Comment: Ya, I was referring to your hack way of doing things where you re-add them to Xcode just so it recognizes them. I agree it is a pain and for now there is no foreseeable fix. Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: Save as is not a solution, especially when you have a large project like mine (with over 650 files).  This is possible, see my answer below.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I didn't say to do a 'save as' on all of the files.  I meant a 'save as' on the single project file itself and have it update the references. This kind of thing is trivial in Visual Studio in Windows.  Yes, I know you can do what you said below, but you do have to do it for all root-level items (i.e. not just groups, but their siblings as well.)  Still, doesn't seem like there's any way to actually do what I want so you'll get the vote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how you do it (I'm using in Xcode 4.3):

**First, move your project file**
1. Start out by closing the Xcode project
1. Move ProjectName.xcodeproj into the folder with all your code
1. Open the XCode project by clicking ProjectName.xcodeproj

**Second, re-map your files**
1. *You do not need to remap the files one by one*, you only need to map the groups
1. Open the "File Inspector" with ⌥⌘1 or `View->Utilities->Show File Inspector`
1. Click each group, then click the square icon (see screenshot below) and choose the folder your project file is in.

Icon to click:
[image]

*"None" will show up when you choose the same folder your .xcodeproj file is in.*

**Conclusion:**
I have a large project which contains ~650 files, but only 12 groups, so it takes just a few minutes to re-map everything.

**Note:**
Sometimes when mapping the files it doesn't recognize a folder change if the name is the same (ie. two folders with the same name).  You may have to pick any other folder temporarily, then choose the actual project folder and the *None* indicator will appear.

Comment: As I commented above, not exactly what I wanted, but this will work, with the one caveat your solution only works if the groups (and any file siblings, which you forgot to mention) have their relativity settings set to the project.  I think however I'm going to write a utility that does this for you.  Still, as I said, this is the closest to a real answer so you get the vote.

Comment: "Relative to Group" is the default for all files in a XCode project.  I don't think you should ever change this as it makes doing this type of thing much harder.

Comment: In the case of shared code libraries that are outside of the project, you absolutely have to do this.  Not changing it works fine for simple projects, but when you get up into much larger-architected products as we have (and why I wanted to change this behavior in the question) it becomes a necessity.

Comment: You are right.  I solved that issue by using "XCode workspaces" for code sharing--this uses multiple Xcode projects, where each project's files are local to it.  This allows me to keep individual project files "relative to group".  And load shared code from arbitrary locations on my computer.  You can also map these shared projects using the same mechanism.

Comment: I have an xcworkspace and moving the main xcodeproj file within its own folder doesn't work using this method. I didn't have to relink the groups, but it lost its schemes.

Comment: Still works in XCode 10. Although you have to remove the path first by clicking the `x` button next to the current folder location then select the new one.